# how to install kubernetes package in minidcos CLI

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos, kubernetes-mesos

I'm trying to install kubernetes in minidcos.

in dcos, there is cli command `dcos package install` to install a specific package as [here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.12/cli/command-reference/dcos-package/dcos-package-install/).

But minidcos doesn't have `minidcos docker package install` or `minidcos package install` as https://minidcos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dcos-docker-cli.html#.

I'm able to install kubernetes using DCOS UI catalog.

how can I install kubernetes in minidcos CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minidcos` is the tool for creating the local DC/OS cluster. Once the cluster is running, you need to use the usual `dcos` cli. If you did not already install it, there are instructions within the DC/OS UI.
`minidcos` is not a substitute for `dcos`.

Answer (score 2):

As Brom said, to install a package on DC/OS and `minidcos` you can and should use the DC/OS CLI.

For example, for a DC/OS Open Source 1.12 cluster, you might run the following to install the DC/OS CLI

```
curl https://downloads.dcos.io/binaries/cli/darwin/x86-64/dcos-1.12/dcos -o dcos
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dcos
sudo mv dcos /usr/local/bin
```

Then use `minidcos docker inspect` to find the web address of the cluster.
Then use `dcos cluster setup http://172.17.0.3` for example to set up the CLI.

That said, Kubernetes is not fully supported yet on `minidcos`.
There is work in progress for this, which can be tracked at https://jira.mesosphere.com/browse/DCOS_OSS-4946.
That issue documents a workaround for a known issue.
In particular, it documents the following commands:

```
dcos task exec -ti kube-node-0-kubelet mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
dcos task exec -ti kube-node-0-kubelet mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
dcos task exec -ti kube-control-plane-0-instance mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
dcos task exec -ti kube-control-plane-0-instance mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
```

These can be adapted to your kubelet and control plane names.
These are set to work with the MKE setup documented at https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/kubernetes/2.1.0-1.12.3/getting-started/installing-mke/.